# Splunk oneshot Lookup Error

Tags: python-2.7, splunk

I am trying to run a onshot search in python that contains a lookup function of a .csv. I can run any other search through my python app as long as it doesn't contain a lookup. When I run the search in spunk it works fine. When I run the lookup in python I get a error saying can't find xxx.csv. Is there a way to use a oneshot search and lookup via python?

Thanks